# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' pnpm monorepo ts-jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, pnpm

I have created pnpm monorepo for microfrontend applicatons.I have added jest configurations in root level, i have one application and two custom libraries in repo but when i tried to run jest test cases, getting unexpected token export.

Project structure

```
apps -> rootapp
packages -> api-lib
jest.config.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json

export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    transform: { '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest' },
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    testEnvironment: "node",
    coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/coverage",
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        `<rootDir>/node_modules`,
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules'],
    projects: ['<rootDir>/packages/*'],
    coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "html"],
}
```

I am getting error while running rootapp

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from './ApiClient';
```

---

```
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  1 | import { useQuery, UseQueryResult } from 'react-query'
> 2 | import { IApiResponse, ApiClient, ApiType } from 'api-lib'
    | 

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/.pnpm/jest-runtime@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.require (src/hooks/useDashboard.ts:2:1)
  at Object.require (src/hooks/index.ts:1:1)
  at Object.require (src/screens/Home.tsx:2:1)
  at Object.require (src/screens/index.ts:1:1)
  at Object.require (src/__test__/Home.test.tsx:4:1)
```